# My select with two tables is not working correctly

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

Im have a table **News** with:

-*id_news* - *Primary Key*

-*title*

-*content*

-*date*

-category - Foreign Key

And then a **Categories** table with:

-*id_category* - *Primary Key*

-*description*

And Im trying to show my categories description in a table and its not working, but my other data is working.

**Im trying like this:**

```
$readNews = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY date DESC");
$readNews ->execute();
$resultReadNews = $readNews ->rowCount();

if(!$resultReadNews >= 1)
{
echo 'There are now news yet';
}

else
{
  echo '<table>';
  echo ' <tr>';
  echo ' <td>Title:</td>';
  echo ' <td>Content:</td>';
  echo ' </tr>';

  while ($resultReadNews = $readNews ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
         $readCat=  $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM categories, newsWHERE id_category = ?");
         $readCat->bindValue(1,$resultReadNews ['category']);
         $readCat->execute();
         $resultReadCat = $readCat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
         $rowsCat = $readCat->rowCount();

         echo '<tr>';
         echo '<td>'.$resultReadNews ['title'].'</td>';
         echo '<td>'.$resultReadNews ['content'].'</td>';
         echo '<td>'.$resultReadCat ['description'].'</td>';
}
```

Do you see where the problem is?

Comment: Could it be that you are selecting `description` but reading other columns?

Comment: Thanks, but I was passing here the code and I put that wrong, but I have $resultReadCat['description'] in my project and its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code for selecting categories is wrong. You try to select description from two tables, you have

```
$readCat=  $pdo->prepare("SELECT description FROM categories,news WHERE id_category= ? AND id_category = category");
         $readCat->bindValue(1,$resultReadNews ['category']);
         $readCat->execute();
         $resultReadCat = $readCat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
         $rowsCat = $readCat->rowCount();
```

But you must have smth like this:

```
$readCat=  $pdo->prepare("SELECT description FROM categories WHERE id_category= ?");
         $readCat->bindValue(1, $resultReadNews ['category']);
         $readCat->execute();
         $resultReadCat = $readCat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
         $rowsCat = $readCat->rowCount();
```

Comment: But we need to use the "1" to bind the value, no?

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting the wrong column name. You have to change this row

```
echo '<td>'.$resultReadCat ['title'].'</td>';
```

for this row:

```
echo '<td>'.$resultReadCat ['description'].'</td>';
```

Comment: I would also suggest to modify the code so you get all the infromaiton in a single call instead of doing it in 2 calls. The SQl statement would look like this: SELECT * FROM noticias LEFT JOIN categories ON noticias.category = categories.id_category

Comment: Well, I solve the problem with the sql statment that I put now on my question! Thanks for your help!